# Automatically linking Java 8 source code with Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, javafx, java-8, installation

In my installation of Eclipse IDE (Mars 4.5) it has not automatically linked rt.jar and jfxrt.jar to src.zip and javafx-src.zip. I know how to do this manually by browsing to the .zip files within the JDK installation.

What I want to know is if there is a way to ensure this happens automatically when installing Eclipse / Java. I'm pretty certain I know someone who didn't link to the source manually and it is linked on their installation.

For example, if you install the JDK before Eclipse, or vice-versa, does this make any difference?

Also, when you make the link, where abouts is the preference information stored on the file system - is it somewhere within the same folder that eclipse.exe exists?

Comment: Have you specified to Eclipse that it should use your JDK installation to run in (via eclipse.ini)?

Comment: I don't think so - how do I do this and where is eclipse.ini located?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that Eclipse is running in your JDK instead of a JRE (The JDK installation typically puts a JRE on the system executable path), you should always specify it via [`eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). The `-vm` option described there tells Eclipse exactly what JVM you want it to run in.

Another option is to add the JDK to the **Installed JREs** section of your Eclipse preferences and set that as the default for all projects. The default JVM used for projects is the same as the one Eclipse itself runs in, so you don't necessarily need to do both.

Once you have the JDK set as the default JVM, you can open a project's Properties, select **Java Build Path** section, then look at the **Libraries** tab. You should see your JDK as the **JRE System Library**, including its `rt.jar` and corresponding source attachment. Like this:

[image]

Comment: I've added in: "-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe" where the path is that of javaw.exe in my JDK folder, however when I run Eclipse it makes no difference - the source code can still not be seen?

Comment: Can you update the question with a screen shot of your project properties like the one in my answer above?

Comment: Without even posting the screenshot I can tell you I have updated eclipse.ini to include: -vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe  Note the JDK directory specifically. But when I then load up Eclipse and go to the Build Path and Libraries tab it's still showing Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib  Note the JRE directory is still appearing. The point being that in updating eclipse.ini it's seemingly doing nothing. It hasn't changed or added a new build path to link to the JDK instead of the JRE.

Comment: Screen shots help, because there's subtleties in there that are hard to describe in detail in comments. Your project may be configured with an absolute JRE instead of the (usual) Execution Environment.

Comment: Also try the part of the answer that says to add the JDK in your **Installed JREs** in the Eclipse Preferences. It might be that you already have the JRE as the default JVM and the JDK isn't overriding that (it should, but maybe it's not for some reason). If the non-JDK JRE is listed there, remove it and replace with your JDK location.