# How do I enable showing fuction explanation on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNwaZ.png)

I would like eclipse to show me explanations for different methods, how do I do that?

Comment: Hower over the function when you have written it. Or use the documentation.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157597/attach-the-java-source-code Or maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873917/automatically-linking-java-8-source-code-with-eclipse-ide Or maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426084/how-do-i-view-jres-source-code-in-eclipse